# build.gradle is not recognize as internal or external command

Tags: java

```
set GRADLE_HOME=C:\gradle\gradle-4.6
set path= %GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%path%
gradle -v
```

But I get the error...

> 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How can I go about fixing this? I have also experienced the following error...

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in
>   your PATH.

Comment: try echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: yes i tried and  i got %JAVA_HOME% back and after that when i try following command C:\javabook2\whatever\src>build.gradle,'build.gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: also my path contains C:\gradle\gradle-4.6\bin and GRADLE_HOME CONTAINS  C:\gradle\gradle-4.6

Comment: I don't use Windows, but can it handle the space after `set path=`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it from the Control Panel instead. Find "Edit Environment Variables."